# NativeScript Looks for custom plugin in the wrong directory

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I recently attempted to install a third party plugin: https://github.com/bradleygore/nativescript-materialdropdownlist and followed the README in order to use it. Nothing seemed out of the ordinary until I went to run my application and I ran into an error. I quickly noticed it's trying to find the plugin in the wrong folder.

```
<Page
        xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
        xmlns:ns="nativescript-pro-ui/sidedrawer"
        xmlns:mdl="nativescript-materialdropdownlist"
        xmlns:drawer="pages/home/shared/drawer"
        xmlns:header="pages/home/shared/header"
        class="page" loaded="onNavigatingTo">
    <header:header title="{{ title }}" openDrawer="{{ openDrawer }}"/>
    <ns:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer" drawerLocation='Left' showOverNavigation='true'>
        <ns:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
            <drawer:drawer active="pages/home/rooms/rooms"/>
        </ns:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
        <ns:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <mdl:MaterialDropdownList col="1" id="ddlColors" itemSeparatorColor="gray" itemRowsHeight="30" items="{{ colors }}" selectedIndex="{{ selectedColorIndex }}"></mdl:MaterialDropdownList>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ns:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    </ns:RadSideDrawer>
</Page>
```

Stack Trace

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: 
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/pages/home/rooms/rooms.xml:16:21
System.err:  > Module '/data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/nativescript-materialdropdownlist' not found for element 'nativescript-materialdropdownlist:MaterialDropdownList'.
System.err:    > com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "/data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/nativescript-materialdropdownlist", relative to: app//
System.err:       com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1088)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:970)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:957)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:941)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:933)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 196, column: 20
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'ScopeError', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 63, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'SourceError', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 74, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 215, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 196, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 148, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'EasySAXParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/easysax/easysax.js', line: 751, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 195, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlStringParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 202, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'parseInternal', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 47, column: 11
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadPage', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 131, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 112, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 131, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 185, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 615, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25
System.err: 
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: 
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/pages/home/rooms/rooms.xml:16:21
System.err:  > Module '/data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/nativescript-materialdropdownlist' not found for element 'nativescript-materialdropdownlist:MaterialDropdownList'.
System.err:    > com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "/data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/nativescript-materialdropdownlist", relative to: app//
System.err:       com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1088)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:970)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:957)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:941)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:933)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 196, column: 20
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'ScopeError', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 63, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'SourceError', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js', line: 74, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 215, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 196, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 148, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'EasySAXParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/easysax/easysax.js', line: 751, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/xml/xml.js', line: 195, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'XmlStringParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 202, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'parseInternal', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 47, column: 11
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadPage', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 131, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 112, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 131, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 185, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 615, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/com.greywallsoftware.GWSInternal/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 20, column: 25
System.err: 
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1088)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:970)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:957)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:941)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:933)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
System.err:     ... 9 more
```

The module is definitely in my node_modules folder, but {N} is trying to load it from /app/nativescript-materialdropdownlist instead of /app/tns_modules/nativescript-materialdropdownlist where it's actually located in the output of build.

I've tried removing the platforms folder and rebuilding. I've tried removing node_modules and re-installing everything. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: The plugin doesn't seem to have been updated in over a year. It is possible that it isn't compatible with the current version of the `tns-core-modules` version >= 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is not compatible with NativeScript 3.x.x,
Consider using [another plugin](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Drop-Down) or implement your own drop-down functionality